# Is $∫ (1/2)εE^2 dV$ in the entire volume of rays propagation $= nhf$?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, wave-particle-duality

I asked it on ChatGPT but it gave kind of a mixed answer contradicting itself in the process several times here is some of it.

> "Kushagra Singh:
> ~so you mean $∫ (1/2)εE^2 dV$ in the entire volume of rays propagation is $nhf$
>
> ChatGPT:~ No, that's not what I meant. The equation $∫ (1/2)εE^2 dV$ represents the total energy of the electromagnetic wave over the entire volume of space in which it exists. This energy includes the energy of all the photons present in the wave, as well as the energy stored in the electric and magnetic fields of the wave.
>
> On the other hand, the equation $E = nhf$ gives the energy of an individual photon, where n is the number of photons and f is the frequency of the wave. This equation is based on the understanding that electromagnetic waves, including light waves, are composed of individual packets of energy called photons.
>
> So, the equation $∫ (1/2)εE^2 dV$ is not equal to $nhf$. They represent different aspects of the electromagnetic wave. The equation $∫ (1/2)εE^2 dV$ gives the total energy of the wave over a given volume of space, while the equation $E = nhf$ gives the energy of an individual photon."

Comment: Keep in mind is this bot is *extremely* bad with physics question. Posting its answers here is mostly a waste of time or a source of confusion, and you should just ask your question and let people provide answers.

Comment: ok will keep it in mind from next time

Comment: Hi Mc'Brainzz. Welcome to Phys.SE. Posting computer-generated text from ChatGPT, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChatGPT doesn't really understand what it is talking about.

But to answer your question:
Suppose you have an electromagnetic wave with a single frequency $f$
(like from a laser), then your formula is nearly correct.
But besides the electric field energy you forgot the magnetic field energy.
(See for example [Energy in Electric and Magnetic Fields](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/engfie.html).)
The correct formula is:

$$\int \left( \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2 \right)dV =nhf$$

This equation connects both aspects of the electromagnetic field.
The left side gives the classical view (electric field $E$ and magnetic field $B$)
and the right side gives the quantum view ($n$ photons).
The total energy in both views is equal.

Comment: yes sorry I forgot about the magnetic component ,  thank you